# How do I design / architect a large, modular mobile web app?

Tags: javascript, mobile, module

### Background

I need to create a potentially very large **HTML/JS mobile web app** that will be delivered as a mobile web site and natively using **Phonegap**. I'm currently working to determine the best way to organize the app itself.

The basic plan is to have many **modules** that will each focus on a different subject of interest . Some of these modules will be very basic (ie, announcements / news) and some will be very complex (ie, sports: team players, schedules, video, etc). There will be a **side-drawer navigation** that will apply to most pages so users can quickly navigate to a different module. There needs to be the ability to **deep-link** within modules. These modules will be created by a variety of developers and vendors.

### Single Page App

Most of the **mobile solutions** I see involve **Single Pages**, which seem like a bad idea to me in this case, since there is the potential for so much memory use. It also seems like it would be difficult to reconcile hash navigation between modules and hash navigation between section within modules. Module development would have to be done with the **app framework** in mind and limits how things can be done by vendors and developers. On the other hand, things aren't getting loaded as often and everything can easily communicate with each other.

### Multiple Page App

Using **multiple pages**, it seems like each module could easily be created in whatever technology a vendor was comfortable with (and could do quickly and cheaply). It would cut down on memory use, but also remove the ability for modules to communicate (a feature that I don't know is necessary for us at this point). I could see making a **javascript** library every module would use for common handling of various events (like logging errors, navigation, etc). Each app navigation between modules would be a new page call, resetting the **DOM**. Each module could use a single page design if it wished.

## Help Me Please

So, is there any common or new knowledge about how things like this should be designed? I'm eager to begin work, but don't want to be rewriting things that may already exist. Do I have any glaring flaws in my reasoning? I'd love to hear from anyone that has insight.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you are considering building any app that you believe will be high volume and of high complexity, you really ought to consider doing native development, or at least use something like Appcelerator where the application will be "compiled" down to native code for better performance. If you are intending to just let any number of developers build their own javascript components that may or may not do a good job of managing limited system resources, so are going to quickly run into application performance issues.

On the other hand, if you are just going for proof of concept and don't mind potentially having to greatly refactor your application architecture when and if you get a sufficient level of complexity, then you may want to simply go with the web app approach.

Really, you need to also be considering your backend service architecture as much or more than the frontend architecture.  that is really where you are going to run into problems down the line in trying to integrate offerings from other developers.

Comment: I agree. I'm having a hard time arguing that with my managers, however.   I am the only developer they have for mobile development, however, and they want the app done fairly quickly (just a few months from now). The goal is to start out with around 8 modules and expand over time to upwards of 30. I said our best option would be to do native development, but they don't want to wait to hire someone to help me, and they want to be able to support multiple platforms. I can't create this huge app on multiple platforms in a short time by myself, which is how we settled on the webapp/phonegap idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar architectural problem to contend with a couple of years ago. It wasn't mobile, but it wasn't entirely web-based either. The target applications were a mix of web sites and desktop apps, with the potential to go mobile in the future.

The interesting part was that there had been two prior attempts at creating a framework that could be used in a variety of situations. The problem, and the reason both attempts failed, was that the developers saw it as a UX problem space. They approached it using several different technologies, but became mired months down the road because they had made assumptions up front and flown the project by the seat of their pants.

My approach was to eschew all the UI discussion completely and focus on a backend architecture that could be approached from any standpoint. To this end, I created a web service that had data going in both directions, and was ultimately serving a mathematical model. The service is being accessed from a variety of sources using different technologies: Flash, Unity, a Google Earth plugin, and finally, from an unrelated web architecture serving up good ol' HTML.

My advice to you, is don't concentrate on the front-end mapping so much as get your back-end right. Once you have a data structure in place, you can build outward, and several issues such as memory management, monolithic app or not, i.e. one page versus many, will almost resolve themselves. Work on creating a great API with lots of good interfaces and you won't fall into a "many chefs" hole. Give a bunch of dispersed developers enough rope, on the other hand, and you'll never find where all the knots are!

The decision whether to ultimately go native API over HTML5-based technology such as Sencha Touch, jQuery Mobile, or Phonegap is an evangelical black hole that will be played out over the coming months and years. Native apps may be more fluid and speedy in some cases, but the investment in resources is something that should be considered. On the other hand, JavaScript developers are lurking around every corner and are not in short supply.

Comment: The modules we're wanting to make are mostly for exposing data to the user. Mostly, the data we will be sending out will be via feeds. I had wanted to make a service that would help with caching the feeds and whatnot, but I don't see that fitting into our timeframe, so each module will have to connect directly to the feeds. The users will not be effecting change on our servers through the mobile app (at least not yet).

Comment: This project has been "fly by the seat of your pants" so far. There's no real customer (a director said we needed to create it), we're basically making up the requirements as we go along (actually, the graphic designer made up the requirements when he made designs and we're going based on them now), and nobody listens to me when I tell them this is a huge project and probably won't be done in time. Yet I know that I'll be the one blamed when it doesn't. I just wish that I could have the chance to make something useful and awesome.

Sorry about the whining. :)

Comment: Not whining. Those are all fair complaints. Bad managers take credit when it works, point fingers when it doesn't. Good managers get out of the way!

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to nail down those requirements.

If you're doing this for yourself or for your own company, then nail down how these modules (co-)operate.

If you are doing this for your employer, then *somebody* there ought to have a clue what they want to see, otherwise, how are you going to build it?

A solution which supports multiple pages, opening and closing modules with no communication is going to require different things than a framework which is responsible for maintaining multiple widgets at the same time, which may or may not communicate through system-calls or services.

There's no way around that -- building services/sandboxing/etc for modules is going to take more work than treating each like a page-change (or making them be literal page-changes).

When you figure out what you want your program to do, start building out an idea of the API you'd like other people to have.
Are you going to provide them with an API for building UI components, or are you going to leave that to their own whims?

Personally, I'd avoid a situation where each module change just replaces iFrames, and then the end-user can do whatever they want in there.
Likewise, I'd avoid situations where you're allowing module-creators to run whatever they'd like in a non-sandboxed environment...  It ends poorly for your end-users (or you, in UK court).
But that's not a concern, yet.

First-concern is *what does your platform do*.

Then figure out what your back-end communication is going to look like, and what interfaces you're going to provide to module creators, and how you're going to get data from your end to theirs (http-based API, REST or whatever else...  ...but work it out WELL, if you don't already have it).

THEN, when you know what your platform is expected to do, AND you have a backend which can serve all kinds of tasks well, figure out what services you're going to provide to content-creators, to make their widgets, and to upload/download data from your service, and sandbox, and the like.

Comment: Yes, requirements would be nice. I rarely have that luxury. I'm usually given an idea and a deadline. Then, once it's out, I get a list of things to change. I tend to get "impossible" projects that NEED to get done right away because a VIP wants it or because of a lack of planning. 
I've told them that this project should have been started a year ago, not a month ago. They don't seem to understand that if they have one developer on the team, they can't devote that developer to other projects and expect the neglected project to progress.